# Fake extensions in a directory with htaccess

Tags: php, json, .htaccess

I need all php files in a directory and all of its subdirectories to be json. So that when I reach for the file with the json extension I will get the php file.

example:

```
/assets/json/file.php      >>> /assets/json/file.json
/assets/json/user/list.php >>> /assets/json/user/list.json
```

I can partially achieve this by adding a `.htaccess` file in the `/assets/json` directory with these rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.json$ $1\.php [L]
```

With these rules I can see the php content while visiting the json file. But I don't want the php file to be visible anymore, so I need to add a redirect, so that when the user type php it will be redirected to the json file (which doesn't exists)

If I add `R=301` the browser will redirect me to `http://localhost/home/localhost/public_html/assets/json/user/list.php` instead of to `http://localhost/assets/json/user/list.json`

how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same .htaccess have another redirect rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (/.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1.json [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.json$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked! As soon as I ma allowed to mark as correct this answer I will do!